# Translate animation & view layout

Tags: android

i'd like to make a translateAnimation in my Android app with the code below :

```
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-400,0);
        anim.setDuration(400);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {                     
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                mlLinearLayout.clearAnimation();
                mlLinearLayout.requestLayout();
                mlLinearLayout.layout(mlLinearLayout.getLeft(), mlLinearLayout.getTop()+400, mlLinearLayout.getRight(), mlLinearLayout.getBottom());
            }
        });
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setFillBefore(false);
        mlLinearLayout.startAnimation(anim);
        active=false;
```

but when this animation was done, the LinearLayout back to his start place even if I rebuild my view with the new position. How can I change it please ?

Comment: From your problem I would guess that setFillAfter was set to false, but clearly it looks like you are setting it.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found solution :

```
            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,400);
            anim.setDuration(400);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {                     
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mlLinearLayout.layout(mlLinearLayout.getLeft(), mlLinearLayout.getTop()+400, mlLinearLayout.getRight(), mlLinearLayout.getBottom());
                }
            });
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(false);
            anim.setFillBefore(false);
            mlLinearLayout.startAnimation(anim);
            active=false;
```

As i rebuild my view after translation, fillafter isn't usefull, Now it's working perfect without lag and jump !